# How to convert bytes to float using ctypes?

Tags: python, floating-point, ctypes

I would like to convert `b'\xd8\x0fI@'` into a `c_float`. I am looking for something like:

```
>>> c_float(bytes=b'\xd8\x0fI@').value
3.1415
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a union:

```
import ctypes as ct

class Convert(ct.Union):
    _fields_ = (("my_bytes", ct.c_char * ct.sizeof(ct.c_float)),
                ("my_float", ct.c_float))

data_to_convert = b'\xd8\x0fI@'
conv = Convert()
conv.my_bytes = data_to_convert
print(conv.my_float)  # prints 3.141592025756836
```

You would probably also want to check the length before doing the conversion.  Without such a check you will get a `ValueError` if you try to use too *long* a sequence of bytes, but it will not alert you if you use one that is too *short*. (The type checking is done for you automatically.)

```
if len(data_to_convert) != len(conv.my_bytes):
    raise ValueError
```

Comment: Changed to make `_fields_` a tuple rather than a list, although the docs have examples of both. Probably doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 0):

Use [unpack](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) from the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) library

```
import ctypes, struct

ctypes.c_float(struct.unpack('<f', b'\xd8\x0fI@')[0]) # c_float(3.141592025756836)
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to use `unpack`... I would like to use `ctypes` only